# The number of distinct terms in a trinomial expansion

Tags: binomial-theorem

$$(x^3 + \frac1{x^3} +1)^{200}$$ is the given expression. How many distinct terms are in this expression when expanded. I know that there are a total of $3^{200}$ terms before combining the terms but I'm struggling to find the distinct terms. Please provide a clear explanation of the answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By distinct you mean “different powers of x”?

Comment: This depends on the definition of "distinct terms". I would assume you consider the term distinct, if they differ by the exponent of $x$.

Comment: This question is almost certainly talking about how many terms will be in the expanded equation after like terms have been collected.

Comment: On one hand I had the same interpretation, on the other I feel like the knowing how many terms make up each of the coefficients is also interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer should be $401$: in the complete expansion of the polynomial above, there are no negative coefficients, there will be no cancellation, so you just need to count how many powers of $x$ appear. Substituting $x^3$ with $y$, it is clear that every power of $y$ between $y^{200}$ and $y^{-200}$ appears. Hence, the answer is $401$.

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain the Substituting $(x)^{3}$ with $y$ bit. Slightly confused on what is y used as here.

Comment: What I was trying to say is the following: let's rewrite your expression as $(y+1+y^{-1})^{200}$, where we put $x^3=y$ (this is not necessary in any way, I just wanted to make my argument more straightforward). At this point, we count how many powers of $y$ appear, and the answer is $401$ as explained above. Now, we substitute back to $x$, which does not change the number of terms of the expression. Hence the answer is $401$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to simplify the problem a bit to explain my method, then you can apply it to this one:

Suppose instead we had:

$$(x+1)^{200}$$

This is $(x+1)(x+1)(x+1)...$

Suppose we wish to find any term (from the $2^{200}$ in the expanded equation, before collecting like terms). We could do this by going through each of the brackets one at a time and selecting either $x$ or $1$. Once we go through every bracket selecting one of the terms, the product of the terms we picked out is one of the terms of the expansion.

Let's suppose we pick $x$ a total of $t$ times, and therefore we pick $1$ a total of $(200-t)$ times. Then the power, $p$, of a given term is:

$$p=(1)(t)+0(200-t)=t$$

Applying this to your equation, can you see we have:

$$p=(3)(t)+(-3)(u)+(0)=3(t-u)$$
This makes it obvious that the powers are *only* multiples of $3$, so you just need to figure out how many are in your range.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

You can take a product of $ k_1 $ terms in $ x^3 $, $ k_2 $ terms in $ x^{-3} $ and $ k_3 $ terms in $ x^0 $, where the same power of $ x $ can be obtained in multiple ways.  In doing this we require $ k_1+k_2 +k_3 = 200 $ and $ 0 \leq k_1, k_2, k_3 \leq 200 $.  Consolidating terms of the same power of $ x $ then results in gathering terms of the form $ x^{3(k_1-k_2)} $.  This yields all distinct powers of $ x^3 $ from $ -200 $ to $+200 $, including zero, implying 401 distinct terms in the expansion.  We note that none cancels since the individual coefficients are all 1.